# Pass an array as environment variable to jboss's standalone.xml

Tags: java, arrays, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am using keycloak 8.0.1, which is on top of WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final, which is running on linux. I need to pass several http proxy values to make keycloak server able to use route planner for outgoing HTTP requests, for example: use proxy01 to reach google and proxy02 to reach amazon.

I cannot use **jboss-cli** since I am using a pipeline to deploy my server - everything should happen in automatic mode.

No problem for the case of a single variable, you can pass it to keycloak that way according to the keycloak's docs https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_proxymappings

You have a **jboss config**

```
<spi name="connectionsHttpClient">
        <provider name="default" enabled="true">
          <properties>
                <property name="proxy-mappings" value="${env.HTTP_PROXY}"/>
          </properties>
        </provider>
</spi>
```

and you have **env settings** in a manner of pattern `HTTP_PROXY=hostnamePattern;proxyUri`.
The pattern is for the keycloak to parse.

Now the multiply proxy values case and the problem.
If you want wildfly to pass an array you should write like this (from keycloak doc's and it is correct) :

```
<spi name="connectionsHttpClient">
    <provider name="default" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property
            name="proxy-mappings"
            value="[&quot;.*\\.(google|googleapis)\\.com;http://www-proxy.acme.com:8080&quot;,&quot;.*\\.acme\\.com;NO_PROXY&quot;,&quot;.*;http://fallback:8080&quot;]"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
```

As you can see you have to:

1 - pass the square brackets `[]` since you need an array, because keycloak expects an array, it will split it by a comma and nexly treat it as String[]
2 - pass the proxy pattern in double quotes `""`
3 - and double quotes in terms of a wildfly should be changed to `&quot;`

The simplified construction looks like this (without `&quot;`) :
`[ "proxyPattern01" , "proxyPattern02" ]`

**The problem is:**
If I put this cozy construction to an environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` and try to catch it in keycloak I can see that this variable *is passed from wildfly to keycloak as a single line that includes to itself: square brackets, double quotes and so on. Keycloak get it as a String that consists of all the proxy values*.
If I put this construction to a wildfly's configuration manually or via jboss-cli it appears in keycloak as an array with two elements - every element consists only of one proxy pattern, and later it will be parsed and processed by keycloak correctly.

**The question is:**
How to pass an array of variables from environment to wildfly so the keycloak can see this as an array with several elements and not as a single String that aggregated all of variables into single line with square brackets?

**Addition #01**
This scenario works, but not appropriate since if you want to change the number of proxies you have to redeploy, not just restart the server with changed vars

```
<property 
  name="proxy-mappings" 
  value="[&quot;${env.AAA}&quot;,&quot;${env.BBB}&quot;,&quot;${env.CCC}&quot;]"/>
```

and

```
AAA='.*\\.firstSite\\.ru;NO_PROXY'
BBB='.*\\.secondSite\\.ru;NO_PROXY'
CCC='.*;http://proxyForAll:8888'
```

**Addition #02**
Little debug history added:
the line from wildfly is accepted in keycloak at line

```
String[] proxyMappings = config.getArray("proxy-mappings");
```

let's see what is getArray(String key) method:

```
JsonNode n = config.get(key);  // key is "proxy-mappings"
```

let's see what is config.get(key);

```
return _children.get(fieldName);   // fieldName is "proxy-mappings"
```

let's see what is _children:

```
protected final Map<String, JsonNode> _children;
```

String is `"proxy-mappings"`, JsonNode is the value from wildfly.
This jsonNode value is of type `ArrayNode` in case I put in wildfly's standalone config file value manually like this:

```
value="[&quot;.*\\.(google|googleapis)\\.com;http://www-proxy.acme.com:8080&quot;,&quot;.*\\.acme\\.com;NO_PROXY&quot;,&quot;.*;http://fallback:8080&quot;]"/>
```

and is of type `TextValue` in case of this syntax:

```
value="${env.HTTP_PROXY}"/>
```

It seems that JsonNode can recognise square brackets in upcoming value and treats it as ArrayNode in case of that wildfly's

```
value=" [ &quot; value01 &quot; , &quot; value02 &quot;, &quot; value03 &quot; ] "
```

and it treats it as TextNode in case of wildfly's

```
value="${env.HTTP_PROXY}"/>
```

And last interesting info from debug:
there is a field

```
private Config.Scope config;
```

of type `JsonConfigProvider` in class `DefaultHttpClientFactory`

In a moment of `DefaultHttpClientFactory` initialises this field refers to an `ObjectNode`, which holds natural json value:

```
{
   "enabled":true,
   "proxy-mappings":[
      ".*\\.one\\.ru;NO_PROXY",
      ".*\\.two\\.ru;NO_PROXY",
      ".*;http://three:8888"
   ]
}
```

It is an array of variables, not a variable with an array inside of it.

Comment: Try to debug DefaultHttpClientFactory.lazyInit() line number 146:
`String[] proxyMappings = config.getArray("proxy-mappings")`
You can open keycloak github repo in IDE and use remote debugging on localhost 8787 (uncomment corresponding JAVA_OPTS in KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.conf)

Comment: @solveMe -> You are absolutely right, this is the place where my string or array arrives (depends on wildfly's configuration for that property). And it is was debugged, that's why I figured out when I received array or string. But that action exposed me the problem, not the solution. In my case with several proxies I get in this very line the array String[] with one argument, that contains all the proxies in one line, and even square brackets included in that single argument as string =)